# Drawning circles in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

i’m trying to plot circles like the image bellow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXYP8.png)
but with command

“Plot with circles “
I can’t decrease the size of the circles. What can i do to plot circles like this?

Some solution to the problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your script and data (minimal example).

Comment: set term postscript enhanced color font "Arial,24";

set border linewidth 2
set xlabel "PC1" offset 0,0.2;
set ylabel "PC2" offset 1.0, -1;
set cblabel "Time (ns)" offset 0.25
set key samplen 2 spacing 2.00 right top horizontal width 0.0;
set tics scale 0
set lmargin 8
set bmargin 3.5
set tmargin 3.5
set rmargin 4
set pm3d
set cbtics 25
set xtics 25
set ytics 25
set cbrange[0:*]
set cbtics nomirror 0,500,10000
set style fill solid 0.7
set pointsize 0.1

set output "pca.eps";
plot "myProjection_out.csv" u ($2):($4):($1) w circles lw 0.1 lc palette t ""

Answer (score 0):

To determine the size of circle, just use:
`set style circle radius graph $value`